# Formatting inside a multiline textbox

Tags: formatting, textbox, xul

Is there any way to put formatting inside a multiline textbox? It cannot be applied to the whole box.
If not, is there a way to make any other text element such as `description` to be selectable and copy-able?

For example:

```
<textbox multiline="true">
    <description style="color: red;">This should be red</description>
</textbox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I misunderstood your question. If you just want to be able to select from a `<description>` element, just set the `-moz-user-select: text` style on it. (You might want to set the cursor too.) Copying is slightly harder though, since you have to handle the keypress/context menu yourself.

Comment: Is there a way to get the selection contents though?

Comment: `window.getSelection()` works, just as it does in a regular web page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's always the `<editor>` element...